# Cannot run program "C:/Users/sa/workspace/test/src/test/swing_sample.java": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java

I have created a java app which has a login button, so that once login button gets clicked,my login javaprogram known as swing_sample gets exectuted and that app popups,but i get this error

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Masslauncher {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Masslauncher window = new Masslauncher();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Masslauncher() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblWelcomeToMohans = new JLabel("Welcome to Mohans appplication");
        lblWelcomeToMohans.setBounds(71, 5, 292, 29);
        lblWelcomeToMohans.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        lblWelcomeToMohans.setBackground(Color.RED);
        lblWelcomeToMohans.setFont(new Font("Harlow Solid Italic", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToMohans);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Login");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Process theProcess = null;
          BufferedReader inStream = null;

          System.out.println("CallHelloPgm.main() invoked");

          // call the Hello class
          try
          {
              theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/sa/workspace/test/src/test/swing_sample.java");
          }
          catch(IOException c)
          {
             System.err.println("Error on exec() method");
             c.printStackTrace();  
          }

          // read from the called program's standard output stream
          try
          {
             inStream = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader( theProcess.getInputStream() ));  
             System.out.println(inStream.readLine());
          }
          catch(IOException c)
          {
             System.err.println("Error on inStream.readLine()");
             c.printStackTrace();  
          }

       } // end method

     // end class


        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(41, 103, 113, 41);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
        btnRegister.setBounds(247, 103, 102, 41);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnRegister);
    }
}

    Error:
    CallHelloPgm.main() invoked
    Error on exec() method
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Users/sa/workspace/test/src/test/swing_sample.java": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at test.Masslauncher$2.actionPerformed(Masslauncher.java:72)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 41 more
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at test.Masslauncher$2.actionPerformed(Masslauncher.java:84)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

THIS is the error i get,basically wen i click login i have my login program to open tHANKS..

Comment: The error is quite clear: a Java source file is not an executable the system could run in any way. You'll have to compile it and run it through the JVM.

Comment: I CHOSE THE DEFAULT APPLICATION AS ECLIPSE ALREDY FOR JAVA FILES,WENI RUN THROUGH CMD ITS OPENING

Comment: That's completely different from what you're doing in code.

Comment: SO I HAVE TO COMPILE AND EXECUTE IT RIGHT?

Comment: Please stop writing in all caps.  We’re trying to help you.  There is no reason to shout at us.